# Set the value for Child Pane

Tags: ios, iphone, inappsettingskit

Using inAppSettingsKit, I'm trying to display the value of a Child Pane element in the summary tableCell.

TableCell correctly display the Title but not the value :/

Here is a snippet of my Root.plist file:

```
<dict>
    <key>IASKViewControllerClass</key>
    <string>SetupBirthViewController</string>
    <key>IASKViewControllerSelector</key>
    <string>init</string>
    <key>Key</key>
    <string>settings_birthYear</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>Né(e) en</string>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PSChildPaneSpecifier</string>
</dict>
```

And my [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] file is like bellow:

```
<dict>
    <key>settings_birthYear</key>
    <string>2009</string>
    <key>enable_preference</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I also display Multi Value cell and it works like a charm...

Anyone to help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child panes aren't really designed for that according to Apple's spec. That said, it'd be certainly possible to add support for this. Look at around line 500 in `IASKAppSettingsViewController.m` and set `cell.detailTextLabel.text` to `[self.settingsStore objectForKey:key]` or your defaultValue.

If you do the extra mile and wrap that in a nice little extra option, we'd be happy to include your contribution ;)

Comment: I'll try to implement this feature...Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ortwin for your answer. Since not all child panes shall display a value I changed the code to:

```
      if ( key ) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.settingsStore objectForKey:key];
      }
```

I don't think we need another key since it was previously not used for child panes anyway. Would be great addition to the official version.